# Layer 3 switch redundancy solution (with vlan's, stp)

Tags: switch, vlan, redundancy, mpls, stp

So basicly I have a setup which I want to get to work but i'm unable to.
It's possible I am overseeing a lot of things but let's get to it anyways.

The current situation is a **network with 4 switches** connected to each other (almost a full mesh, 1 link is missing intentionally). I am using *omniswitches* (2 times model 6850 and the other 2 are 6400). I am not working on cisco systems, as I am trying to recreate this lab physicly.
But the truth is, that the principle should stay the same, right? So any tips or even packet tracer solutions would come in handy.

Important to know is that the 2 6850 switches need to be configered as **layer 3 switches**. The other 2 above don't have this requirement. As I am pretty new to configuring switches on layer 3 so I might have messed up here already.
The main objective or goal (then this testlab is succesful) is when the switches are configured so that if 1 of the 2 (who function on layer 3) fails, the other one will take over and everything stays the same.

I created a couple of vlan's and I tagged a few ports with the following commands:

```
vlan 21 name "vlan21"  
ip interface vlan71 address 10.20.11.1/24 vlan 21  
vlan 21 802.1q 1/1  
vlan 21 802.1q 1/2  
vlan 21 802.1q 1/3  
vlan 21 802.1q 1/4
```

Now by default spanning tree is enabled. And that's fine. But how can I now make sure that the 1 of the 2 switches will provide support in case the other fails.

I thought that configuring *MPLS* would solve this problem but either I messed up or MPLS isn't a suitable solution for this.

Does anyone have experience with this or a similar scenario? Any documentation can come in handy as well!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you missed out the commands you meant to include?

Comment: Indeed! They do not represent much though. I fixed it. Thx for the reply.

Comment: Please include a drawing how things are wired.

Comment: I have found a solution for 1 vlan. I will post details in a couple of days when I'm back. I'll add some pic's as well.

Comment: Does your feature set support VRRP ?

Comment: The 2 6850 do, the 6400 don't (they don't have to actually).
I managed to configure it correctly and made a huge logical error (therefore at this point I think I asked the wrong question).

I'll try to answer in a response soon the structure so it may be of help for other people :)